# Make Apache or IIS add a header if a certain query string is present

Tags: apache-2.2, iis

Can I make Apache or IIS add a specific header if a certain query string is present?

I want every URL with "download=1" in the query string to be served with `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

<sub>Weird question title because originally this was about Apache only, but now I've added IIS too.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` with `mod_headers` make this possible as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)download=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*?([^/]*))$ $1 [E=DOWNLOAD:$2]
Header set "Content-Disposition" "attachment; filename=\"%{DOWNLOAD}e\"" env=DOWNLOAD
```

<strike>Haven't tested this with anything containing non-ASCII or spaces. Those will probably end up showing in the file name URL-escaped, i.e. "%20" etc.</strike>
Edit: Special characters should work just fine.

---

I had to do the same on IIS 7.5, so here's the way to do it: place the following XML into a site's `<system.webServer><rewrite> ...` section:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="DownloadAnything">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern=".*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(^|&amp;)download=1(&amp;|$)" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

(obviously if you already have an `<outboundRules>` element, place only the rule inside the existing element)